# ansible win_command fails but works when command run manually

Tags: windows-server-2016, ansible, wds

I'm trying to run New-WdsClient PowerShell cmdlet or wdsutil /add-device, I don't really care which one gets used in the end, so long as it works.

When I run 'wdsutil.exe /add-device /device:new_client /id:aabbccddeeff /BootImagePath:"Boot\x64\Images\boot-(6).wim" ' it works, when I run the same from Ansible I get

`"stdout_lines": [
        "",
        "Windows Deployment Services Management Utility [Version 10.0.14393.0]",
        "© 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.",
        "",
        "",
        "An error occurred while trying to execute the command.",
        "Error Code: 0xC103013A",
        "Error Description: The specified server name is invalid or does not exist in the directory service.",
        ""`

I'm completely stumped.

The Ansible role is just:

`- name: Pre Stage WDS Client
  win_command: powershell.exe -
  args:
    stdin: 'wdsutil.exe /add-device /device:{{ var_wds_client_name }} /id:{{ var_wds_client_mac }} /BootImagePath:"Boot\x64\Images\boot-(6).wim"'`

Using New-WdsClient I don't even get this far...

Any ideas?

-- EDIT 1 --

When I run the win_whoami as adhoc it works:

`ansible wds-server --become --become-method runas --become-user DOMAIN\Administrator --module-name win_whoami 2> /dev/null| egrep "SeDebug|High"
            "account_name": "High Mandatory Level",
        "account_name": "High Mandatory Level",
        "SeDebugPrivilege": "enabled"`

When I run wdsutil as adhoc like:
`ansible wds-server --become --become-method runas --become-user DOMAIN\Administrator --module-name win_command -a "wdsutil.exe /add-device /device:client /id:0001a5a0c267 /BootImagePath:Boot\x64\Images\boot-(6).wim"` I get:

`Windows Deployment Services Management Utility [Version 10.0.14393.0]
© 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`

An error occurred while trying to execute the command.
Error Code: 0xC103013A
Error Description: The specified server name is invalid or does not exist in the directory service.

non-zero return code

Comment: I see that Ansible is correctly connecting to the WDS server, however I am still suspecting that an authentication problem is happening somewhere. A `wdsutil.exe /add-device` command line [requires communication with AD domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/using-the-add-device-command) and authentication errors (specifically, Kerberos credential delegation errors) being masked by generic messages may happen in command-line tools. Please, could you elaborate on how you've configured the connection to your WDS server in your Ansible inventory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, apologies all.

The Ansible serve is a RHEL box and it is actually talking to an intermediate Windows box which then talks to the WDS server.

One of my collegues found this link which solved [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/190093-wds-name-and-authorise-access-denied) problem for us.

Thanks all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, as I don't have a Windows WDS deployment handy to perform tests.

I believe the task is not running via Ansible due to lack of elevated privileges that `wdsutil` requires, according to [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wdsutil). You may need to use the `become` keyword for the task to work:

```
- name: Pre Stage WDS Client
  win_command: powershell.exe -
  args:
    stdin: 'wdsutil.exe /add-device /device:{{ var_wds_client_name }} /id:{{ var_wds_client_mac }} /BootImagePath:"Boot\x64\Images\boot-(6).wim"'
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
```

Or, alternatively, invoking `wdsutil` directly:

```
- name: Pre Stage WDS Client
  win_command: 'wdsutil.exe /add-device /device:{{ var_wds_client_name }} /id:{{ var_wds_client_mac }} /BootImagePath:"Boot\x64\Images\boot-(6).wim"'
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
```

---

Check whether administrative rights are granted to Ansible by using the ad-hoc call below:

```
$ ansible windows_wds_server --become --become-method runas --module-name win_whoami
```

The return JSON object should have `privileges.SeDebugPrivilege` attribute set to `enabled`.

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#administrative-rights

Comment: Many thanks but still no good.  Running the win_whoami as above worked and SeDebugPrivilege was enabled although I had to add --become-user as well